# How to query a XML document-node produced by json-to-xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am looking to import JSON data to be processed with XSLT and get a result XML. I do understand that the parsing done by "json-to-xml" means the result of a map consisting of other maps, arrays, keys and values. What I don't follow is what syntax is supposed to be used to query the map. It seem the first step is always to parse the complete tag content on root level from the JSON file. I assume that any further queries after the parsing of "json-to-xml", is being done toward the document produced node.

In below example I start with a JSON file that has a hierarchy, but the end result should be almost complete flat.
The "general" and "unit-definitions" (in JSON file) should be used as guidance about how to transform the data, e.g. which attribute to use, but that level of keys in the JSON should not appear in the XML result.

I have read the XSL 3.0 specification in terms of "json-to-xml" but I do not find any examples of the query towards the produced document node. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-json-to-xml

Below code is also found here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS6Y/1

**To clarify the question:** How can one query the json-to-xml produced map, to get below "wanted result"?

**My attempts:**

**XML data source file:**

```
<data>
{
    "general": {
      "Language": "English",
      "Country": "Sweden"
    },

    "units-definitions": {
      "SEK": "iso4217:SEK"
    }
  }
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
    xmlns:root="http://www.example.org/1"
    xmlns:flat="http://www.example.org/2"
>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <!-- New root tag name -->
      <root:report>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)"/>
      </root:report>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template
  match="*[@key]"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
>
    <xsl:element name="flat:{@key}">
      <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">period0</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<root:report xmlns:root="http://www.example.org/1" xmlns:flat="http://www.example.org/2">
   <flat:general contextRef="period0">
      <flat:Language contextRef="period0">English</flat:Language>
      <flat:Country contextRef="period0">Sweden</flat:Country>
   </flat:general>
   <flat:units-definitions contextRef="period0">
      <flat:SEK contextRef="period0">iso4217:SEK</flat:SEK>
   </flat:units-definitions>
</root:report>
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root:report
  xmlns:root="http://www.example.org/1"
  xmlns:flat="http://www.example.org/2"
  >
      <flat:Language contextRef="period0">English</base:Language>
      <flat:Country contextRef="period0">Sweden</base:Country>
      <flat:SEK contextRef="balance0">iso4217:SEK</base:SEK>
</root:report>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flatten some structure you usually process `//*` or in that case only the leaf elements `//*[@key and not(*)]`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:root="http://www.example.org/1"
  xmlns:flat="http://www.example.org/2"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <root:report>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)//*[@key and not(*)]"/>
    </root:report>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[@key]">
    <xsl:element name="flat:{@key}">
      <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">period0</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The base result looks correct. Only missing is to have a way where each template matches e.g. "general", "units-definitions", this is needed in order to specify specific attributes for that match. Should I open a new question about that?

Comment: @Toolbox, yes, I think so, in your description of the wanted result it seemd like those items higher up the hierarchy produced no output so I ignored them. If they do matter perhaps ask a new question where detail exactly what the task is.

Answer (score 2):

To produce your wanted result, I don't think I would use `json-to-xml()`, I would process the JSON directly. Something like:

```
<xsl:template match="data">
    <root:report>
      <xsl:variable name="json" select="parse-json(.)"/>
      <flat:Language contextRef="period0">{?general?Language}</flat:Language>
      <flat:Country contextRef="period0">{?general?Country}</flat:Country>
      <flat:SEK contextRef="period0">{?units-definitions?SEK}</flat:SEK>
    </root:report>
</xsl:template>
```

I see from your comments on @MartinHonnen's answer that you've simplified the actual problem, but I think this approach should prove sufficiently extensible.

Comment: I took exactly your XSL suggestion and the data.json described in the question, but the output shows the exact format as seen in xsl, e.g: "{?general?Language}", not the value from JSON.

Comment: You failed to set expand-text="yes", something I always put in my stylesheet boilerplate.

Comment: I will open a separate question to keep the answers of this question short and clean.